# Apply filters to all visuals like tableau in aws quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tableau-api, amazon-quicksight

I have been working with aws quicksight since 2 weeks, i have gone through udemy courses but i could not find any global filter for aws quicksight. Please help me to apply filter.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure I'm getting your question, but if I am:

You can edit your filters to apply each one of them to one or more (or even all) your visuals with this dropdown menu:

[Edit Filter Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvqwU.png)

You'll find it whenever you edit a created filter, right on top of the panel to edit it.